# Java Worker Thread to Wait

Tags: java, multithreading, worker

I have a thread working in the background and but it doesn't always has work to do. I want it to wait for data to be passed by the main thread and then continue working.

At first I thought that's what `wait()` and `notify()` were for but it seems to work the other way around.

How do I do that?

Comment: Sounds like you want a [`BlockingQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) -- this is a very common requirement for producer-consumer problems. Try not to reinvent the wheel ;-)

Comment: Didn't know about this one. Make an answer about it and I will accept it ;)

Comment: as a side note, wait/notify work perfectly well for this (producer publishes to shared collection and calls notify, consumer waits until notified then reads from shared collection), but nowadays the concurrent utilities (aka BlockingQueue) simplify things such that wait/notify generally no longer need to be used directly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12439402/java-worker-thread-to-wait#comment16726214_12439402).

> Sounds like you want a [`BlockingQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) -- this is a very common requirement for producer-consumer problems. Try not to reinvent the wheel ;-)

There exist multiple [`BlockingQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) implementations, e.g. a bounded [`ArrayBlockingQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html), an unbounded [`LinkedBlockingQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html), a hand-off [`SynchronousQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/SynchronousQueue.html), even a [`PriorityBlockingQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/PriorityBlockingQueue.html). All `BlockingDeque`s and `TransferQueue`s are also `BlockingQueue`s ;-)

Comment: you wouldn't want to use SynchronousQueue as that would block the main thread if the background thread was currently busy.

Comment: @jtahlborn you're correct, but I didn't suggest to use it -- I merely stated that it is indeed a `BlockingQueue`. I specified it was *hand-off*-style and linked to the specification for him to read more.

Comment: no worries, i'm just adding some more info to assist the OP in choosing the best BlockingQueue impl.

Comment: @jtahlborn I personally think Peter's answer below is much better ;-p

Answer (score 6):

I would suggest you use an ExecutorService. I combines a queue with a Thread pool.

You submit tasks to it which are performed in the background as it can and you can obtain the result if you want.

```
ExecutorService service = Executors.newWhateverPool();
service.submit(new Runnable() {  your task here });
```